# MongoDB with Spring Boot and document containing similar fields

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I'm current trying to access an object in my MongoDB database.

My object is stored this format in db:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("some object id"), // mongodb gives this id
"my_id" : "Given id by myself",
"url" : "Some string data"
}
```

Myobj class:

```
@Document(collection = "MYOBJ")
public class Myobj {

    @Id
    private ObjectId _id;

    private String my_id;

    private String url;
    // getters and setters and other methods
}
```

I want to fetch this object using my_id field. In my repository I have these:

```
public interface MyobjRepository extends MongoRepository<Myobj, String> {
    Myobj findBy_id(ObjectId _id);
    Myobj findByMy_id(String my_id);
}
```

But it fails to build, it gives me this error:

> No property my found for type Myobj! Did you mean 'url'?

I suppose it cannot differantiate between my_id and _id. How can I solve this issue without changing my object in the database?

Without findByMy_id method it was working. That method causes compile error.

Comment: FYI you are not using anything to do with the JPA API there. Kindly dont tag it as such

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you inside interface `MyobjRepository` set *String* as Id of that template `MongoRepository<Myobj, String>`, and you need to set *ObjectId* like `MongoRepository<Myobj, ObjectId>` because you said in your `Myobj` class that you  will be use `ObjectId _id`  for `@Id`

Am I right ?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure about which one to use as an ID.

I don't want to use mongodb id (_id) for reaching to the database because I don't have that reference in my SQL table. I have reference for my_id in my SQL table, so I want to use ID as that field.

Comment: @kur30704 Ok, but if you want to search over that entity you need to object have same Id type in Repository like are in Entity. So only two situation :1) entity: `@Id` is `ObjectId` and repository look like: `MongoRepository<Myobj, ObjectId>` , or 2) entity: `@Id` is `String` and repository look like: `MongoRepository<Myobj, String>`

Comment: I will use my_id to search objects in mongodb. What should my repository look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Document(collection = "MYOBJ")
public class Myobj {
    private ObjectId _id;

    @Id
    private String my_id;

    private String url;

}
public interface MyobjRepository extends MongoRepository<Myobj, String> {
    Myobj findBy_id(ObjectId _id);
    Myobj findByMy_id(String my_id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort, BUT, I still have the same error. I have disabled "findBy_id" field, and again the same error.

If I comment out "findByMy_id" and add "findByUrl", it works, but I want to use my_id field for the tabel